# Matching Value from an SQL db to XML

Tags: php, xml

I'm pretty new to programming so bear with me.

I have an XML File like as follows:

```
<item>
 <SKU>123</SKU>
 <price>$12.99</price>
<item>
<item>
 <SKU>456</SKU>
 <price>$14.99</price>
<item>
```

And I have a SQL table of values like as follows:

```
+----+----------+
| SKU   | Price |
+----+----------+
| 123   | $9.99 |
| 456   |$10.00 |
| 789   | $1.00 |
+----+----------+
```

I want to look up each SKU from the SQL database and see if that SKU exists in the XML file. I also want to match the SKUs in the SQL table to the SKUs in the XML file and write out the price of each (so for Example: SKU 456, $14.99, $10.00).

I have no idea where to even begin. Some questions:

1) I think I could figure out a way to do things if I copied the XML values into another SQL database doing a simple inner join. Is there a way to do this without copying the xml values to a database?

A general direction of what I should be researching would be fantastic!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use JSON instead of XML this would make much more sense.  You may want to put the other 456 sku value up in your table.  Right now I have to assume there's another record for 456 that has a price of $14.99.

Comment: JSON is for javascript. If this isn't going to be clientside for any reason there is no reason to involve a browser.

Comment: @cpattersonv1 Unless this data is a standalone xml file, I would use json server side.  Server side can parse json into an array just as fast as client side.

Comment: If it's already an XML document there is no reason to convert it to JSON to parse it the same as you would an XML file. Also the JSON parser is included with PHP 5.2.0 by default. If they're using a host they may not be able to install it (if they're using an older version).

Comment: @cpattersonv1 I wasn't saying convert the xml but to use json from the get go. Unless its a true standalone file in which its only ran on server start.  And most shared servers have at least 5.2 installed by now.

Comment: @TL if he's importing from something like Amazon or an RSS feed he may not have that control.

Comment: You'll want to research PHP PDO for database part, and http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.xml.php

Comment: Using JSON is much easier to work with and much more excepted for dynamic data.

Comment: Yes, it's coming from the eBay API.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) available since PHP 5.1.2. I know everyone is talking about JSON but XML is much more widely used at the moment.

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<document>
<item>
 <SKU>123</SKU>
 <price>$12.99</price>
</item>
<item>
 <SKU>456</SKU>
 <price>$14.99</price>
</item>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```